# Отобразить посты из определенной таксономии

Tags: wordpress

```js
  <h3><?php single_term_title(''); ?></h3>
  <ul class="demo">
<?php
$posts = get_posts( array(
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'orderby'     => 'date',
 'order'       => 'DESC',
 'include'     => array(),
 'exclude'     => array(),
 'meta_key'    => '',
 'meta_value'  =>'',
 'post_type'   => 'mypostype',
) );

foreach( $posts as $post ){
 setup_postdata($post);
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a></li>';

}

wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>

</ul>
```

У меня есть страница WordPress, где у меня отображается список таксономий из определенного custom_post_type. Как сделать, чтобы при клике на таксономию, на странице taxonomy-'mytaxonomy'.php отобразился список всех постов из таксономию, которую я нажал на предыдущей странице? этот кoд возвращает мне название таксономии плюс все посты из всех таксономии. Что  нужно добавить чтобы получить желаемый результат?

Comment: Добавить для начала стандартный loop WordPress в шаблон и показать остальной код, чтобы понимать о чем речь.

Comment: @mihdan можете помочь?

Comment: Пост тайп пост содержит таксономии tag и category, а в таксономиях содержится term. Вы уверены, что кликаете на таксономию?